# get template checkbox names

Tags: javascript, html, templates, cgi

How to get the checkbox names when that form is loaded by html template. in Java Script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var names = [];
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    if(inputs[i].type == 'checkbox') names.push(inputs[i].name);
}
```

Will give you all their names in an array if you're not using jQuery. You can dump that push() call and do whatever you need to there if you just want to operate on checkboxes.

Just remember, if you have a ton of inputs on your page this will be a slow operation.

Answer (score 1):

if you know jquery 
its easy
use

```
$(document).ready(function() 
        { 

                $('input:checkbox').each(function() 
                { 
                 do ....   
                }); 

        });
```

if you use only js,
run over elements and check if element.type == 'checkbox'